# How do i write a stream to csv file - node.js

Tags: node.js, csv, fs

```
  request.post({url: "https://api.flipkart.com/listing/downloadListings",form: formDataListings}, function(e,r,body){
    var fs = require('fs');
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('download.csv');
    body.pipe(writeStream);
  })
```

I want to store the csv stream and download the csv file

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `pipe()`, don't use a callback:

```
request.post({
  url: "https://api.flipkart.com/listing/downloadListings",
  form: formDataListings
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('download.csv'));
```